# Replace pandas dataframe column with another dataframe column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have some DataFrame, in the first one the columns just include id's, like below:

```
df1:

f_id  l_id  p_id s_id
0       0    1 1
1       1    2 2
```

In other DataFrames, I have the id column of first one and those data:

```
df2:

f_id    f_name
0       Johen
1       Joe


df3:

l_id    l_name
0       Ardi
1       Peykan
```

I want to replace the id column with the data, for example instead of f_id 0 place John

I want this:

```
result:

f_id   l_id   p_id  s_id
Johen   Ardi    1     1 
Joe    Peykan   2     2
```

DataFrames lengths are not same and the id's has been meesed up.

Comment: please provide the expected output for clarity

Comment: Added to question. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update by position/index: you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all your dataframes to a single one after reshaping to Series. Then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.update.html) `df1` in place:

```
dfs = [df2, df3]
df1.update(pd.concat([d.set_index(d.columns[0]).squeeze().rename(d.columns[0])
                      for d in dfs], axis=1))
```

output:

```
    f_id    l_id  p_id  s_id
0  Johen    Ardi     1     1
1    Joe  Peykan     2     2
```

proof of reproducibility:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'f_id': [0, 1], 'l_id': [0, 1], 'p_id': [1, 2], 's_id': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'f_id': [0, 1], 'f_name': ['Johen', 'Joe']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'l_id': [0, 1], 'l_name': ['Ardi', 'Peykan']})

print('Original')
print(df1)

dfs = [df2, df3]
df1.update(pd.concat([d.set_index(d.columns[0]).squeeze().rename(d.columns[0])
                      for d in dfs], axis=1))

print('\nAfter update:')
print(df1)
```

output:

```
Original
   f_id  l_id  p_id  s_id
0     0     0     1     1
1     1     1     2     2

After update:
    f_id    l_id  p_id  s_id
0  Johen    Ardi     1     1
1    Joe  Peykan     2     2
```

##### alternative (not what is wanted)

Or, if you want to use the original value as key:

```
dfs = [df2, df3]
sub = {d.columns[0]: d.set_index(d.columns[0]).squeeze() for d in dfs}
df1.update(df[df1.columns.intersection(sub)].apply(lambda d: d.map(sub[d.name])))
```

output:

```
    f_id    l_id  p_id  s_id
0  Johen  Peykan     1     1
1    Joe     1.1     2     2
```

Comment: the result is not like yours it's the df1 without changes

Comment: @ijavadddd OK, then use the first approach in my answer ;)

Comment: first and second don't act like your resualt

Comment: How is the first one different? The output is identical. Please provide a counter-example if needed.

Comment: the first one return df1 with no additional data

Comment: @ijavadddd this is incorrect, it doesn't return anything it updates `df1` in place making `df1` the provided output

Comment: See the fully reproducible code. If this "*doesn't work*" for you, please provide a similar proof of reproducibility in your question.

Comment: Your answer have some problem, first one my dataframes lengths are'nt same , they have diffrent size and the ids are not respectively and they are has been messed up

Comment: Well, I'd rather say your question is not clear enough (non-representative inputs, absence of logic description). I can only try to **guess** what you want for now ;)